# How to test a context in React?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-context

I've implemented a context :

```
import { createContext } from "react"

const initialState = {
    type: "info",
    visibile: true,
    setVisible: () => { },
    darkmode: false
}
const context = createContext(initialState)

export default context
```

But when I want to test it using [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/), I got confused about what should I test and How to test it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this,

Context File,

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react"

const initialState = {
    type: "info",
    visibile: true,
    darkmode: false
}

export const Context = createContext()

export function Provider({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)

  // using like this gives me ability to provide
  // a function that can change the context data
  const setVisible = val => setState({ ...state, visibile: val })

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ ...state, setVisible }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

in Provider (using FunctionalComponent),

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider as ContextProvider } from './context.jsx'
import SomeComponent from './Consumer'
import SomeComponent2 from './Consumer2'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
     <div>
       <SomeComponent />
       blah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah
       <SomeComponent2 />
      </div>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

in Consumer (using FunctionalComponent),

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import  { Context } from './context'

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const contextData = useContext(Context)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      contextData.setVisible(!contextData.visibile)
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(timer)
  }, [contextData])

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Consumer 1 (Consuming & Changing) </h2>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(contextData, null, 4)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[See live Example](https://react-mx7xmm.stackblitz.io)

Assuming u want to how to use context

Comment: Well, your answer has improved the context but in my question, I was talking about the unit test.

Comment: But how your consumer receives a value from the provider ?